# How can I merge 2 Delaunay triangulations / Voronoï diagrams?

Tags: triangulation, voronoi-diagram

I am building a Voronoï diagram using both Delaunay triangulation and a divide and conquer paradigm but how can I merge multiple diagrams efficiently ?

As shown in this picture, I can make Voronoï diagrams but have yet to find a way to efficiently merge them :

[image]

I have heard a lot about convex hulls but this would require me to :

- be able to define the convex hull
- be able to check if a Delaunay vertex is inside or outside the convex hull ( and reject the ones that are outside )
- merge two or more convex hulls

I wish to know if this method can work or not ( am I missing an important point ? ) or if I should rather try an other method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By carefully analyze their relations with the boundary, you can determine the points of one block that influence another block. The method is described in this article:
http://www.mrzv.org/publications/distributed-delaunay/